# Best method to add new column to (postgres)SQL database, Using a python script or SQL function?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I have database that has a column that is a Georgian date like{YYYYMMDD}. I want to have a column(or 3 for year, month and day) for Jalai date. I can easily write and script using python to convert Georgian date  to Jalali. This is what I write in python:

```
import jdatetime as jdt
georgian = str(20170828)
def GtoJ(georgian):
    jalai = jdt.GregorianToJalali(int(georgian[:4]),int(georgian[4:6]),int(georgian[-2:]))
#     print('{}{:02}{:02}'.format(jalai.jyear,jalai.jmonth,jalai.jday))
    return '{}{:02}{:02}'.format(jalai.jyear,jalai.jmonth,jalai.jday)

print(GtoJ(georgian)) ##13960606
```

Assume I create an empty column in my postgresql database with name jdate, using sqlalchemy or any other sql engine I  update every row with following codes:

```
for date in history_tabel_date:
    jdate = GtoJ(str(date))
    con.execute('update history_tale jdate= value_jdate where date = {}'.format(date))
```

What is the way to write a sql function that do the same thing?

Generally is it a good idea to write script outside sql or sql functions are better and recommended?

Answer (score 1):

When using a database as a resource for a script, the bottleneck occurs when the the script and the database are going back and forth due to creating a connection, transporting the data, etc. Therefore, you should be looking towards doing most of the data processing at either end and reducing the number of queries (`INSERTS`, `UPDATES`, `DELETES`) to the bare minimum.

If you're looking at performing the function on the database side, you could consider using [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/plpython.html) which is a

> procedural language allows PostgreSQL functions to be written in the Python language.

Comment: that's great aydow, In documentations I didn't see any import statement, can I import packages that I installed using pip?

Comment: [import statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023080/how-are-import-statements-in-plpython-handled)

Comment: i think this might help for [importing pip-installed libraries](https://blag.felixhummel.de/postgresql/plpython.html). i haven't used it before but if the library is in your `PYTHONPATH`, then it should work..

Comment: hi @Mehdi, could you please accept or at least up vote the answer considering that it was helpful to you? many thanks